# Upgrade Semantic Bundle/SMW 1.9 to SMW 2.2

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

We're upgrading from Semantic MediaWiki 1.9.2 to version 2.2 and will no longer use the Semantic Bundle.

So we no longer include SemanticBundleSettings.php and SemanticBundle.php in LocalSettings.php but use Composer and the vendor/autoload.php.

The Special:Version page shows the correct version and most things seem to work well but there are some issues.

For example when editing a template this message appears: "This page is not enabled for semantic in-text annotations due to namespace restrictions. Details about how to enable the namespace is described on the configuration help page".
(assuming this has something to do with upgrading)

My question: is there some roadmap to upgrade in a structured way rather then trial-and-error?

I've read [Upgrade from SMW 1.9+ for MW 1.22+](https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Installation/Upgrade_from_SMW_1.9%2B_for_MW_1.22%2B) and the [release notes for SMW 2.0](https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki_2.0) but this does not give me enough information.

Comment: You might want to consider asking this via the issue list at https://github.com/SemanticMediaWiki/SemanticMediaWiki/issues